# Skyrim Audio Choppy

Tags: sound, wine, steam, playonlinux

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04.2. When I load Skyrim via PlayonLinux, the audio always becomes choppy and unbearable at times. Is there a solution?

Comment: try changing wine to windows version 2000 and report back

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skyrim with PlayOnLinux audio is choppy](http://askubuntu.com/questions/614991/skyrim-with-playonlinux-audio-is-choppy)

Answer (score -1):

You did not give many details, but you have to know that Windows programs that run under Wine (PlayOnLinux uses Wine) will not have the same performance like under Windows itself, and bugs occur mainly with games. If your entire system's sound is OK and only Skyrim has this bug, then probably it is a Wine performance bug.

Comment: I'm with Eduardo on this one. You're basically running a rom built application. It won't have every attribute processing as smoothly as on it's original console operating system. When is comes to gaming, you might be better off running Skyrim on either XBox 360 or a PS3.. which is a bummer, Skyrim is a good game and I also have a love for linux so I can agree with ya that this isn't a very comfortable issue lol good luck tho man :)