# Skyrim audio extremely choppy

Tags: sound, wine, games, playonlinux

I've bought Skyrim LE yesterday, installed it via PlayOnLinux. The game is working fine graphically, however the audio is severely distorted with a varying stutter depending on how many different sounds are being played at once. Specs: Ubuntu 14.04, nVidia GTX 760 (331.113, nvidia-331), ASUS M5A97 R2.0, AMD FX-6300

Here's a recording of the game menu: https://youtu.be/92VgTXrhgS0
That's the top quality. The more audio at once, the more distortion appears.

I've spent the whole day searching for solutions, including suspending PulseAudio, changing sample rates on Wine, using alsadrv, windows7 mode, windows2k mode, windows xp mode... Basically all the first pages on Google for any combination of keywords "skyrim ubuntu audio stutter", and any combination of solutions. What I could gather is that its probably a "buffer underrun", but the solutions above did not change the results.

I don't know which info is necessary, so please tell me and I'll edit with the relevant data.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Skyrim with PlayOnLinux audio is choppy](http://askubuntu.com/questions/614991/skyrim-with-playonlinux-audio-is-choppy)

Comment: @LeoVerto That question talks about static and tone, while my audio pops in an out really fast. It sounds a lot like the symptoms of this very old bug (which is probably unrelated considering it's been fixed 2 years ago): https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/alsa-plugins/+bug/503174

Comment: Have you at least tried the suggest solution of not installing Skyrim directly but Steam instead? On another note, I found [another](https://askubuntu.com/questions/621293/skyrim-audio-choppy) similar bug mentioning sound problems with Skyrim when using PlayOnLinux.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another method. That might work. Go into terminal and type in this command

winecfg

This should open a menu that will have some features on it. Go to sound and hit test sound to see if it is working. You can maybe mess around a little bit here to select your default system input and output sounds. I have mine all set to system default. Although I don't use many programs on win that need sound. Also another thing to try is on your game go to sound and select your speakers or speaker drivers. If you can. Sometimes the game might not be running the correct sound driver.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is because your audio cord is not plugged in fully. Also make sure your audio drivers are up to date and are the right audio drivers for your speakers. Maybe your audio cord is broken. Or just try reinstalling wine.

Comment: I'm pretty sure the cord and the output device are in great shape, any other application works perfectly. Skyrim is a widespread problematic application.

Comment: Sorry I dont know I just thought that because most of the time thats why my sound isnt working

Comment: No problem, I'm sorry if I sounded harsh. English is not my primary language.

Comment: You didnt sound harsh at all